# Cross contract calls - Difference between {Contract}Ref and build_call().delegate()

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call

What is the difference in these two approaches for cross contract calls? One uses the `{Contract}Ref` and the other uses the `build_call().delegate()` method. Both methods do not require the contract to be instantiated and only require the code hash.

```rust
let adder = AdderRef::new(accumulator.clone(), staker_code_hash)
                .endowment(0)
                .code_hash(adder_code_hash)
                .salt_bytes(salt)
                .instantiate();

adder.inc(by)
```

```rust
build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                 .delegate(self.staker_code_hash)
                 .exec_input(
                     ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("get_stake")))
                 )
                 .returns::<i32>()
                 .try_invoke() {
                     Ok(value) => value,
                     Err(err) => match err {
                         ink_env::Error::Decode(err) => panic!("Failed to decode return value: {:?}", err.to_string()),
                         _ => panic!("Failed to invoke `stake`"),
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: You are using `build_call().delegate`, but you can also use `build_call().call` which takes callee AccountId as a parameter and you do not need hash.
https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.2.0/ink_env/call/struct.CallBuilder.html#method.call
That makes `build_call()` to be more usable if you call already deployed contract.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the contract interface reference object in advance for using buil_call. You just pass the contract address with function selector and its parameter in low-level call format.

Comment: These 2 code snippets are both separate examples. They show 2 different methods for call cross contract. One approach uses the contract `Ref` and the other uses the `code_hash` for the `delegate()` method.